# correct way to handle unhandedled exceptions in boost asio and restart the processing

Tags: c++, exception, boost-asio

What is the proper way to handle unhandled exceptions(unhandled in the callback provided to recv ) in the handlers I provide to boost asio?

My approach is something like

```
  while (true)
    {
        try
        {
        //create listener that takes my_io_service as param
        my_io_service.run(); 
        return; //normal way to cancel processing
        }
        //catches
        //after catches:
        lock_guard<mutex> _(running_mtx);
        if ( ! my_io_service.stopped())  // one A pointed ! here is wrong
            my_io_service.reset();
        // and after this we go back to the beginning of the while loop :)
    }
```

and I stop my_io_service like this:

```
    void stopListening()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> _(running_mtx);
        if ( ! my_io_service.stopped())
            my_io_service.stop();
}
```

Comment: `What is the proper way to handle unhandled exceptions` Um

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit edited, what i meant recv handler doesnt catch his exceptions

Comment: In exception handler you shouldn't call `reset`, just call `run` again.

Comment: @IgorR without handlers run will return immediately, and if exception happened that means registering a handler was also skipped = no handlers

Comment: I do not understand the question enough to provide an answer, but wanted to accentuate that calling [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) while there are unfinished `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` calls results in undefined behavior.  Hence, some form of synchronization, such as a [`barrier`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers), needs to be used to guarantee all threads have returned from processing the `io_service` prior to calling `reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you mean. But as i understand, you wonder about exceptions that are thrown and not about error codes passed to the handler, right? In that case, `try` and `catch` sure does work but if you only want to make sure against exceptions of `io_service.run()` (and not those generated within the handler for example), you can as well use the non throwing overload: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload2.html

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
my_io_service.run(ec);
```

Now you will not get any exceptions by that line but you should probably inspect `ec` afterwards as any error that would normally cause an exception to be thrown will get stored in there. This `ec` has nothing to do with the `error_code` passed to your handler, that one indicates how the async operation went (while the `.run` did its job), while this one gets set if `.run` itself encountered any problems.

edit: If you care about exceptions thrown within the handler, you should put a `try catch` block in there so you handle them as needed. For example, you might want to start a new async operation.

Comment: From what I can see from documentation my problem is that service runs out of work, so it gets stopped. Because documentation says exceptions alone should NOT stop it Effect of exceptions thrown from handlers    http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html

Comment: and yes im talking about exceptions in the handler aka in my code

Comment: I see, so i misunderstood you. In that case, i personally would still try to make my handler non-throwing (maybe by having it pass complicated work to another thread or whatever) but else your handling looks like a good idea, except that in the catch block, i would `stop()` the service if it is not yet `stopped()` and then `reset()` it no matter what. That should happen seldom enough to not make the little more work a problem and it is a little bit safer about what state the `io_service` is in. If there are other async operations waiting, they would be cancelled however.

Comment: It just occured to me: You `reset()` only if it is NOT stopped. That seems to be wrong way around. You should not need to `reset()` if it is not `stopped()` and you need to `reset()` if it is. However, this looks like a question for someone with a little bit more insight into asios inner workings and i would expect someone to show up and explain everything much better. And by someone i mean probably Tanner Sansbury from my experience :)

Comment: if I reset it on stopped I have race condition with stop_listening, or do I? who knows :)

Comment: i know, i just tested it, it is a race condition

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [giving your io_service work to chew on via an io_service::work object?](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html)

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
```

will keep the io_service functioning and waiting for work.

If you need to be able to allow all operations to finish and the io_service to end, you can use this idiom:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
auto_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work(
new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service));
...
work.reset(); // Allow run() to exit.
```

All of this is covered in the boost documentation, and solves your ACTUAL problem: io_service runs out of work and returns, making you have strange control paths.

Answer (score -1):

This would increase cost of your handlers, but I would go for additional wrapper you pass to recv, i.e. instead of

```
boost::asio::async_read(
   socket,
   buffer,
   boost::bind(
       &c::m,
       object,
       boost::asio::placeholders::error
   )
);
```

I would do

```
void wrapper(boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code &)> handler, const boost::system::error_code & ec)
{
   try
   {
       handler(ec);
   }
   catch (...) // this is very bad practice, but if you insist...
   {
      // ... maybe at least log the problem
   }
}

// ...

boost::asio::async_read(
   socket,
   buffer,
   boost::bind(
       wrapper,
       boost::bind(
           &c::m,
           object,
           boost::asio::placeholders::error
       ),
       boost::asio::placeholders::error
   )
);
```

With the above wrapper, you will not propagate any exception to `io_service::run()`.

One humble advice: if you have unhandled (unexpected) exceptions being thrown from handlers, then you have bigger problem with the design, than just restarting `io_service::run()`. If I understand your question correctly and you are going to ignore all errors (exceptions) which nobody took care of silently, then please consider, whether you really want to do that.

Comment: I disagree... making handler noexcept would require all of them to take care of exceptions... a lot of repetitive code...  I mean if the can take care of it fine, but if they cant... why bother with catch and rethrow

Comment: What are you planning to do with the exception outside of the handler? You will hardly know the context or error (unless you keep it in the exception). If you still consider handling "gereral" exceptions from all kind of handlers in one place, you can wrap them and do not disturb `io_service::run()`'s work. This gives clear separation of boost::asio layer and your code (handlers).